# how to convert arraylist data to string array in android

Tags: java, android, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

here i'm trying to get latitude and longitude values from json url it stored in array normally i can view it logcat also but i need to get those values from arraylist to string array then only i can load it google map. if any one know answer for this let me know pls....

```
            try {
                **arraylist1.clear();**


                jsonarray = json.getJSONArray("LatlogValu");
                 Log.d("Haaaaaaaaaaaa", ""+json);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                     Log.d("H11111111111111111111111111", ""+jsonarray.length());
                    **HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    json = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);


                    map.put("PubName", json.getString("PubName"));
                    map.put("PubID", json.getString("PubID"));
                    map.put("Lat", json.getString("Lat"));

                    map.put("Long", json.getString("Long"));


                    arraylist1.add(map);**


                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
                Log.e("ERROR_^>^>^>^>^>^>^>^>^^>^>^^>^", "Failed data was:\n" + result);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
public String[] toArray(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list){
    String[] strArray = new String[list.size() * 2];
    int i = 0;
    for (HashMap<String, String> map : list) {
        strArray[i++] = map.get("Lat");
        strArray[i++] = map.get("Long");
    }
    return strArray;
}
```